# Count how many $(a_1,...,a_n)$ such that $a_1+...+a_n\ge n^2$ and $a_1^2+...+a_n^2\le n^3+1$.

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a_1,...a_n$ be positive integers . Find how many ordered $(a_1,...,a_n)$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^na_k\ge n^2\text{ and }\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2\le n^3+1.$$

This problem is from the book *Problems from the Book*. Unfortunately the book doesn't provide answers but this problem was in the CS section so
I know  I should use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I don't know how. I tried to use $$n\sum_{k=1}^na_k\ge \left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right)^2$$ but that doesn't give anything.

Comment: When you're asking questions from some source, you should copy verbatim. The original problem in the book had the terms as all  integers, you've made them positive reals. Further, not sure how you got the inequality you tried to use...

Comment: I fixed the typos @M

Comment: It was by no means a  simple typo. You should not change a question drastically after answers are posted. You should have retained this question  and asked a new one in which $a_n$'s are integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider (with $\sum$ representing sums over $i \in [n]$):
$$\sum(a_i-n)^2  =\sum a_i^2 - 2n\sum a_i+n\cdot n^2\leqslant (n^3+1)-2n\cdot n^2+n^3=1$$

Now as this is the sum of integer squares we must have $\sum (a_i-n)^2 \in\{0, 1\}$.

In case the sum is zero, we get the unique solution $a_i=n$ for all $i$.
Else we must have one of the terms as $n\pm1$ while all remaining are $n$.  It is easy to show in those cases that either $\sum a_i^2> n^3+1$ or $\sum a_i < n^2$.

---

P.S. It is not hard to convert the above into a CS inequality proof,  perhaps you can try that yourself.

Comment: Can you check my method using CS? @Macavity

Answer (score 1):

OP had said $a_k$'s were real numbers. It has now been changed to positive integers. This answer is for the original question.

There are infinitely many. Take $a_k=n+\epsilon$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$. You will see that the first inequality  holds for any $\epsilon >0$ and  the second one holds for all $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small. [$0<\epsilon <\frac  1{2n^{2}+n}$ will do.].

Comment: I am really sorry the original problem says that $a_k$'s are positive integers

Comment: Unfair to downvote the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this inequality $$n\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2\ge \left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right)^2$$
Is the key to solving the problem

Note that $$n^4+n\ge n\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2\ge \left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right)^2\ge n^4$$
$$n^3+1\ge \sum_{k=1}^na_k^2\ge n^3$$

Which means $$\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2= n^3 \text{ or }n^3+1$$
The first corresponds to $a_k=n$ and the second is impossible.